# using router.navigateToRoute() to navigate to child route

Tags: aurelia

I have the following app structure:

```
-app
    -route1
    -route2
        -child1
        -child2
```

I would like to navigate to `route2/child1` from `route1`. Using `this.router.navigateToRoute(name of child route)` results in an error: `A route with name 'ranking' could not be found`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known no-workaround issue, due to the nature of lazy loading. As you cannot know what route will be available in `route2` until you have loaded it successfully. Typically we can use `.navigate` with parameter for this.